# How do JavaScript transformers process different AST structures?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, babeljs, transpiler

I am currently playing around https://astexplorer.net/. In there, you can choose different parsers (acorn, babylon, esprima) that generate different structures of AST. You can also choose different types of transformers (babel, prettier, tslint) that convert the AST into the resulting source code. [See sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBrVN.png).

[image]

Transformers look similar to this:

```
export default function (babel) {
  const { types: t } = babel;

  return {
    name: "ast-transform", // not required
    visitor: {
      Identifier(path) {
        path.node.name = path.node.name.split('').reverse().join('');
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Considering that AST structures are different, how do these transformer methods actually accept the AST into a format that it will understand? Is there an additional layer of 'normalization'?

Additionally, who passes the AST into these methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the AST structures are different*"? They all contain the same kind of elements, don't they? As you can judge from the parameter name of `ast-transform`, it just uses the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: What I mean with this is that the generated AST structure of each parser looks different (i.e. different set of properties/fields). 

With regards to the transform method, they look different from each other. Not all has `visitor`. See `jscodeshift` transformer for example.

Comment: I don't see what's so different, they basically all use the [ES-Tree format](https://github.com/estree/estree). That some parsers spit out additional properties (like token location information) doesn't really matter.

Comment: They all somehow traverse the tree and transform it based on the node types and contents. ast-transformer allows anyone to do it with the visitor pattern, jscodeshift does its own thing.